# During testing custom python wrapper with ctypes, 'OSError: exception: access violation reading' is occurred

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ctypes

I'm making a custom python wrapper for using the 'Opencv Tracking Algorithm' in python. 
After ignored several problems, I just made a basic part of the wrapper and tested it. 
But It didn't work, with **OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000001** 
I googled similar problems and found several similar cases. However, Those are not the cases that apply to my problem. 
 
Is there someone who can help the noob?

Here is my python code

```
from ctypes import *
Load_DLL=WinDLL('C:/pracpy/prac.dll')
loadfunc = Load_DLL['loadkcfTracker']
import cv2
videoname = c_char_p(b'param.json')
loadfunc.argtypes = [c_char_p]
tracker = loadfunc(videoname)
```

Here is my c++ dll project code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

__declspec(dllexport) cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> loadkcfTracker(char* filename) {
    return cv::Algorithm::load<cv::TrackerKCF>(filename);
}
```

Comment: Which line triggers the error?

Comment: It's `ctypes` not `cpptypes`.  It doesn't understand C++ classes.  You need `extern "C"` interfaces and stick to C-compatible types and structs when exporting from C++.

Comment: @CristiFati in the last line, 'tracker = loadfunc(videoname)'

Comment: @MarkTolonen Oh ... I see , then I should find C++ library for python. thank you for your accurate answer !